# Why text goes out of div?

Tags: html, css

Could someone explain me why text goes out of div?  And I cannot center vertically. 
Why it's out of ul list box?

```css
.experience-section {
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.experience-section .figure {
  font-family: 'Garamond-Italic';
  background: url('../img/x.svg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 283px;
  width: 283px;
}

.experience-section .figure ul li:first-child {
  font-size: 193px;
}

.experience-section .figure ul li:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  margin-top: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="experience-section" style="background-image:url(assets/img/welcome-bg-1.jpg);">
    <div class="figure">
      <ul>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>years</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Our words talk about experience</h3>
    <p>Nunc rhoncus advenenatis est nec hdrerit. Donec eu mauris sapien. Maecen id metus pellentesque ex feugiat cursus cenustsque feugiatus cursus cesius alteri.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Twd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The size of the font is less than the div height but due to the **default value of line-height**, the text goes out of Div.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.experience-section {
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.experience-section .figure {
  font-family: 'Garamond-Italic';
  background: url('../img/x.svg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 283px;
}

.experience-section .figure ul li:first-child {
  font-size: 193px;
}

.experience-section .figure ul li:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  margin-top: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="experience-section" style="background-image:url(assets/img/welcome-bg-1.jpg);">
    <div class="figure">
      <ul>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>years</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Our words talk about experience</h3>
    <p>Nunc rhoncus advenenatis est nec hdrerit. Donec eu mauris sapien. Maecen id metus pellentesque ex feugiat cursus cenustsque feugiatus cursus cesius alteri.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you changed and what does that change do? You might want to add that so it's easier to understand how this solves the problem :).

Comment: I have changed the height property. 
.experience-section .figure{
height: auto;
}
It works for me

Answer (score 0):

**the reason is** you hardcoded a `height:283px` to `.experience-section .figure`. Since the font size is high, it was overlapping.you can set height auto to fix it.